# What does it mean the RNG should Pass "Chi-square test"?

Tags: c++, random

Does it mean the I should use http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/chi_squared_distribution/ in c++?

Does it mean the numbers that are generated don't have the same probability instead probability is distributed according the Chi square function? (One number has a larger probability to be generate vs other number?)

Comment: No, it means they should exhibit no correlation as measured by the statistical chi-squared test.

Comment: You mean Chi square test checks if randomness is uniform across all numbers? And `chi_square_distribution` is not uniform random number generator, which is completely different compared with Chi square test?